# Google Play Store on android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have created a virtual device API 17 using Google API but after starting the devices I can only see google location apps like Google Maps, Local, Navigation and there is Google Settings too but I can't find Google Play Store even though Google Play Services is listed among the installed applications.

Comment: You can try BlueStack

Comment: @Abhishek link is dead